# Gradle DSL method not found 'compile()' (firebase conflict)

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication, libraries

[MY ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e27KI.jpg)

I've been looking through many posts on stackoverflow with this problem and almost everyone saying that main problem that can cause situation like this is compiling libraries in project-level gradle file, but my file dependencies looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
```

also, my app-level gradle file looks like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    complie 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

it points on 46 line which equals 
    complie 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so sorry if given information maybe be not correct, appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo.

You wrote `complie` instead of `compile`